# Does iterating with foreach loop over a dictionary require normal hashtable accesses?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary

I am writing an application that is primarily performance intensive. After writing a quick benchmark today I have found that dictionary access time is significantly slower than array access time (up to a 100 times), though both are O(1). I tried finding similar results on the internet, but to no avail. Does this seem right? It makes sense to me as there is hashing involved for the dictionary, and not for the array.

I am now weighing up the pros and cons of the dictionary, and considering if I should attempt a faster implementation. In at least 3 instances of my application I loop through all my dictionaries (there are quite a few) with a foreach loop. So now to get to my question, does the foreach loop have to go through the "slow" (I speak relatively here) hashing process, or does it simply maintain an internal list that it can quickly iterate over? If this is the case, I'd be more likely to stick with the dictionary.

For some extra info, the application is a simple 2D game, and the dictionary is to store in game entities. There really are very many though. And yes, I already have a working solution. This is post-optimization, not pre.

Here is the benchmark I wrote. It may be very wrong, as I'm no expert in the field:

```
        public static int dict(Dictionary<key,int> dict, key k)
        {
            int i;
            //dict.TryGetValue(k,out i);
            i = dict[k];  //both these version yield the same results

            return i;
        }

        public static int arr(int[,] arr, key k)
        {
            int i;
            i = arr[k.x, k.y];

            return i;
        }

        public struct key
        {
            public int x, y;

            public key (int x, int y){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            int dim = 256;
            Dictionary<key,int> dictVar = new Dictionary<key,int>(dim*dim*10);

            int[,] arrVar = new int[dim,dim];

            for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dim; ++j)
                {
                    arrVar[i, j] = i + j * i;
                    dictVar.Add(new key(i, j), i + i * j);
                }  
            }

            const int iterations = 1000000;
            key k = new key(200, 200);
            TestTime(dict, dictVar, k, iterations);
            TestTime(arr, arrVar, k, iterations);
        }

        public static void TestTime<T1, T2, TR>(Func<T1, T2, TR> action, T1 obj1,
                                                T2 obj2, int iterations)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
                action(obj1, obj2);
            Console.WriteLine(action.Method.Name + " took " + stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }
```

Comment: How are you iterating over the dictionary?  `foreach (var key in dict.Keys) { var value = dict[key]; }` is much slower than `foreach (var item in dict) { var key = item.Key; var value = item.Value; }`.

Comment: Post the code you used to run the benchmarks.

Comment: I'm doing the foreach (var item in dict). In this case I actually don't even need the key at all. Just the values are important.

Comment: Use [`GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c6ftx8b.aspx) which should be faster than using `foreach`. A Dictionary is not designed for enumeration but for accessing single items by key.

Comment: foreach uses GetEnumerator internally.  There might be a slight overhead (I haven't inspected IL), but it can't be much.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin: It omits exception handling.

Comment: Yip, I am aware of this. Thanks. The reason I did the comparison was to get an idea of how fast my application could potentially be if I dropped the dictionary for an array implementation. This likely consume too much memory in my case. I understand that all this cannot be told from my post, however I considered it unnecessary to write pages and pages to explain the exact details of what I am attempting to achieve. Thanks for the effort though :P

Comment: Wow, after implemented GetEnumerator everywhere I could, my performance is much, MUCH better. Maybe I'm overlooking something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maintains an internal list it loops over, but the list is of type `Entry<TKey, TValue>[]`, so it has to construct a KeyValuePair each time.  I would guess this is what is causing the slowdown.

Comment: I guess this answers my question then, thanks. Can accept in 2 minutes :)